# How pull multiple ranges as a function parameter using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I've seen some examples of how to get multiple ranges as a function parameter, but given my data structure, I haven't been able to get this to work.

When the mouse is on Age, for example, and the function is run, it is to grab the highlighted cells as a range, since I'll be using these data for charts.

Here's how the data is:
[image]

Here's the piece of code that deals with the data CURRENTLY - if those cells are manually selected and the script is run.

```
Public Sub sMigrateFixToList(blnTranspose As Boolean, _
                          strMigrationType As String, _
                          MultiRng As Range)
    Dim strProcedure As String
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim strDestRange As String
    Dim lngNumRows As Long
    Dim lngNumCols As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim t As Long
        
    ' Enable Error Handler
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    
    ' Name Proc for Error Handler Mesasage
    strProcedure = "sMigrateToList"

    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        Call MsgBox("Go to the right sheet")
        GoTo Exit_Proc:
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    k = MigrationList.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    t = IIf(k = 1, 2, k + 2)
    objRange.Copy

    MigrationList.Cells(t, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=blnTranspose
    Select Case strMigrationType
        Case "T"
            MigrationList.Cells(t - 1, 1).Value2 = "<<TABLE>>"
       
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
Exit_Proc:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 1004
            Err.Clear
            Call MsgBox("Não pode selecionar blocos de células não alinhados.", _
                   vbInformation + vbOKOnly, _
                   g_STR_ERRMESSTITLECRITICAL)
        Case Else
            Call MsgBox("Error number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
                   "Description: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
                   "Code: " & strProcedure, _
                   vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
                   g_STR_ERRMESSTITLECRITICAL)
    End Select
    Resume Exit_Proc
End Sub
```

The idea is to have this range made of multiple ranges fixed and pass it to other function being called below as a parameter:

```
Public Sub sMigrateToListAsTable()
    Call sMigrateToList(False, "T", Selection)
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: If "Age" is selected then you'd use something like `Selection.Cells(1).MergeArea.EntireRow.Columns(6)` and `Selection.Cells(1).MergeArea.EntireRow.Columns(8)` to access the highlighted ranges.

Comment: Hi, @TimWilliams! Thanks! Would you happen to know why it keeps replacing Age for TRUE once the code is run?

Comment: I would comment out the error handler while testing, so you can see exactly where the problems are.  `sMigrateFixToList` doesn't seem to use the parameter `MultiRng` at all, so I'm not sure I follow the requirements here.  `MigrationList` is a worksheet?  What is `objRange` ?

Comment: Hi, @TimWilliams! ```sMigrateFixToList``` sets selection, which is one of the function parameters when calling that... I can get the selected cells to the destination. My issue is that when doing that, it causes that Age replacement...
```MIgrationList``` is a worksheet and ```objRange``` used to be the Selection which I am now trying to replace for fixed ranges, so that the use doesn't have to select the ranges manually every time they're to run the code. Thank you!